# override modules

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, module, overrides

Joomla 3.3 - beginner
I am creating my first template, and after installing it to be ready for testing. I accidentally clicked on "mod_login" in the "create override" under my template settings. and this message appeared.[image: screenshot]

I don't understand it and I'm afraid that this may affect something in my future customizing trip.

so how can i undo this action ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template Overrides are used to allow the developers to make changes to the layout of a module without having to hack into the core of the module code which as mentioned in a lot of previous answers is bad.

Template overrides are simply duplicates of the (normally) **default.php** file from a module. In you case, **mod_login** has been duplicated and added to the required folder to allow you to perform a template override. Seeing as I assume you do not wish to use the override, simply delete **mod_login** from the following location

```
templates/ahmedasharaf/html
```

Simple as that. Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

One of the most powerful Joomla features is the ability to override component and module views.

**About Module Layout Overrides**

Modules, like components, are set up in a particular directory structure.

/modules
  /mod_latest_news
    /tmpl
      default.php   (the layout)
    helper.php   (a helper file containing data logic)
    mod_latest_news.php   (the main module file)
    mod_latest_news.xml   (the installation XML file)
Similar to components, under the main module directory (in the example, mod_latest_news) there is a /tmpl/ directory. There is usually only one layout file but depending on who wrote the module, and how it is written, there could be more.

As for components, the layout override for a module must be placed in particular way. Using Beez as an example again, you will see the following structure:

/templates
  /beez
    /html
      /mod_latest_news   (this directory matches the module directory name)
        default.php   (this file matches the layout file name)
The structure for module overrides is again quite simple: /html/mod_module_name/layout_file_name.php.

Copying or Creating Layout Files
The rhuk_milkyway template does not have any layout overrides for any modules. If we want to override the default layout for Latest News module, we need to copy this file:

/modules/mod_latest_news/tmpl/default.php

to this location, creating the approriate directories in the event they don't already exist:

/templates/rhuk_milkyway/html/mod_latest_news/default.php

You need to take a little care with overriding module layout because there are a number of different ways that modules can or have been designed so you need to treat each one individually.

http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides#Module_Layout_Overrides

Here you can find the full explanation about overrides:

**Understanding Output Overrides**
http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides

Answer (score 1):

Simple, go into `templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html` and delete the `mod_login` folder.

However this is made for easy customizing of templates, so its worthwhile to use if you are making your own template. Its not needed but really handy to keep the look and feel of a template uniform.

All the override function does in the admin is create the html/override_folder for you, this used to be done manually so its just a helpful extra feature to save time.