# No category title in the articles category module

Tags: joomla-3.x

In Joomla 3, I'm listing articles of several categories using the articles - category module.

When the articles are displayed, there should be a title for each category.

But instead, a black dot is being displayed, as per below image.

In J 2.5 this was working OK, but why not in J3?

[image]

Comment: It sounds to me like this is a CSS problem. Since you say it works in 2.5, you should try to identify the selectors you're using for the titles and then see what kind of styles are being applied to them in 3.x. Try using Firebug or something similar...

Comment: @mattosmat it isn't rendering the title. It should output HTML like <h3>title</h3>

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself. Not sure this is a Joomla bug, but thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267711/joomla-3-articles-category-module-override-with-category-image-and-description) and some head scratching I added this line:

```
<h3<?php echo $item_heading; ?>><?php echo $group_name; ?></h3<?php echo $item_heading; ?>>
```

After:

```
<?php foreach ($list as $group_name => $group) : ?>
        <li>
```

In file `mod_articles_category/tmpl/default`

Comment: Since this seems to be an override, consider making the appropriate template override for the module. Check also here: [Module Override](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/override-modules/2205#2205) and [Layout Overrides in Joomla](http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla)